# Why does curl terminate an http request to my server early when an early response is received, but http requests from my browser frontend don't?

Tags: javascript, curl, https, playframework, xmlhttprequest

I have a https route in my API server that accepts file uploads. There's some validation for the uploads and if, for example, one of the query parameters is invalid the server rejects the upload before consuming the entire request body (which can be really huge).

When I run a request against this API with curl (or from Insomnia, which I think just uses curl under the hood), and the server returns a response before consuming the entire body, curl terminates without continuing to upload data even though it has not sent the entire payload yet.

The curl command:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://api.example.com/v0/projects/38/media?filename=somethingInvalid' \
  --header 'content-type: video/mp4' \
  --cookie session=orMaybeIAmInvalid \
  --data '<gigantic chunk of binary here>'
```

This terminates in under a second, and the server returns 400 with some response like `your stuff is wrong yo`. However, if the query parameter is valid, the upload takes about 5 minutes. So this is all working as intended: I don't want to make the user wait minutes and minutes for the 400 that's not based on the file's contents at all.

The same request has the opposite behaviour from my frontend web application. If I run an xmlhttprequest request with the same configuration, even if the web server has reached the point where it is trying to return 400 and no longer cares about the request body being uploaded, the browser keeps chugging along for 5 minutes before even parsing that it has received 400. Why is that?

I say "where it is trying to return 400" because I'm not exactly sure how the underlying technologies work here. I have, in my web server which is built in play framework, this line that's just returning 400:

```
if (stuff.isInvalid()) {
  return completedFuture(badRequest("your stuff is wrong yo"));
}
```

But, come to think of it, I'm actually pretty surprised that this works at all with curl given that the request body has not been entirely consumed at this point. So as much as I am asking "why doesn't this browser request work the way I want it to" I'm also asking what particular avenue of research I need to do to understand what is even going on here.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `curl` is checking for a response concurrently with the sending the request, and it notices that a response has already occurred before it finishes sending the request. That's not normal webserver behavior, and apparently it treats it as meaning that it doesn't need to complete the request.

The browser's logic is different, it doesn't start reading from the network until after it has completed sending the entire request.

When the query parameter is valid, you should wait for the post data to be received completely before sending the response, then `curl` won't terminate the request. That will still allow you to complete processing asynchronously.

Comment: Hmm. Right, but do you know if there would be a way, on the server side, to signal to the browser to stop sending the request?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to close the connection, but then the user might get an error. HTTP is a simple request-response protocol, it's not designed for asynchrony like that. For what you want, you'd have to split it into two steps.